# TCPDF, mark a text

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

as I try to mark the word differences between the descriptions in my program, TCPDF always marks too many words as it should.

Just have a look in a code example:

```
$text = '100% nach schriftl. Zusage, ohne Zusage auch bei 
<span style="background-color:rgb(255,255,187)">Notfalleinweisung und</span> einziger benötigter 
<span style="background-color:rgb(255,255,187)">Behandlungsmöglichkeit.</span>';

$this->writeHTML($text);
```

after the word "Notfalleinweisung" is everything marked.

is there a bug in TCPDF or something?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have problem in someone else. Your code [work as expected](http://i.imgur.com/JeTmK4s.png) in my PDF generator;